# Customizing validation error message for a custom validation rule in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

In my controller, I'm trying to customize error message for a custom validation rule. The problem is the custom rule doesn't have a name, so I'm facing a bit of difficulty in customizing the error message for this rule.

#### Controller.php

```
$request->validate([
    "address.house" => ['bail', 'string', 'nullable', 'max:100', new CustomRule]
],
[
    "address.house.hereWillBeTheNameOfCustomRule" => "Custom message for custom rule"
]);
```

#### CustomRule.php

```
public function message()
{
    return "I want to override this message.";
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have defined `message()` method in your CustomRule class? 
Or you can add message in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file with index 'custom_rule'.

Comment: I have defined message method. I want to override that message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined `message()` method in your CustomRule class to return a validation message e.g.

```
public function message()
{
    return 'The :attribute must be match custom rule.';
}
```

OR
can add custom validation message to `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file with index 'custom_rule' e.g.

```
'custom_rule' => 'The :attribute must be match custom rule.'
```

If you want to use a custom message on run-time, use it as like below:

```
'address.house.custom_rule' => 'The :attribute must be match custom rule'
```

For more details check laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects
Hope it makes sense for you, feel free to ask if still have any query.

Comment: In "address.house.custom_rule", "custom_rule" is the name of the custom rule , right? How to set this name?

Comment: Yes! 'custom_rule' is the name of the custom rule, I guessed this from your rule Class name i.e. `CustomRule`.
If you have a different validation-rule class name then simply split class name words with underscore (_) to get the rule name.

Comment: What is the outcome or error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting "I want to override this message." as validation error message. But I want "Custom message for custom rule" as validation error message.

Comment: Can you please try overriding any other verification message (just to confirm, everything else is working as aspected - debug). let say `max` rule: 
```
 [
    "address.house.max" => "my custom max rule"
]
```